How to set contentPadding like LazyColumn for Column with verticalScroll in Jetpack Compose?
LazyColumn(
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(bottom = 20.dp,top = 12.dp),
) { /* items */ }

How to achieve the same behaviour using Column and verticalScroll Modifier?
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
)


Here you go:
Column(
  modifier = Modifier.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
) {
  Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(12.dp))
  // content
  Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
}

this will give you same effect as if it is a LazyColumn with contentPadding.

Column(
modifier = Modifier
.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
.padding(bottom = 20.dp,top=12.dp),
) {
   
}

Modifier order first adding scroll state and padding value.

Padding is usually done with the padding modifier:
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(bottom = 20.dp, top = 12.dp)
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
) {
    // ...
}

LazyLists are an exception due to their lazy behavior and undefined size, so they have an explicit contentPadding parameter that works a little bit differently (with the same visual results, though).
